# How would I discover all field mappings in an Informatica repository?

Tags: repository, report, field, target, informatica

Within an Informatica repository, how I might I generate a report to show, from a high level, how every field in every target was derived? For example I'd like to show:

- Whether a field was "simply" passed through from a source
- Whether a field was computed and/or transformed and/or aggregated, etc., based on one or more source fields and perhaps external factors

I know this is a vague question, but this is a question that I myself have been asked to answer.

Might a query of Informatica's tables yield this kind of information? I'm new both to Informatica and to this specific repository.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Informatica provides repository database views for you to retrieve information from the repository. Please see the Informatica PowerCenter Repository Guide for more detailed information about the views. It may be possible to get that info what you are looking for from the views, but I think is not easy to get this kind of info. Repository views gives you e.g. general information about the source and target tables.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to achieve using the Repository. Look for Data Lineage available in PowerCenter Metadata Manager. If you don't have this available and would need to analyze Source to Target dependencies for a single workflow, you can try a tool I've created here: [xmlAnalyzer](http://maciejg-app2.appspot.com/xmlAnalyzer) It's a simple, online tool to chceck all mappings within an XML file and list all Source-Target dependencies. You can find out for example how many Source fields have impact on a given Target field. It will not show however what are the transformations along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You will find following tool from informatica marketplace useful for this requriement. 
https://community.informatica.com/solutions/xml_reporter_for_informatica

Comment: This is link only answer. Those are are not considered good answers.